# Delete and refresh list in Android

Tags: android, listview, sql-delete

I made an app for clothes. I display all the clothes in a categorized list. When the user clicks on a list item, they have the ability to delete it or to edit it. When an item is deleted, the list does not refresh and I have to get out and then to get in again to the particular list to see that is gone.

I am trying to refresh the list automatically. Do I need an intent? Or is there any other way?

**Details.java**

```
ImageButton deleteButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.delete_clothes);
deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (handler.deleteCloth(String.valueOf(extras.getInt("id")))) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cloth has been deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

**Dresses.java**

```
private void loadClothesData() {

    clothes = handler.readAllDresses();
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, clothes);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.invalidateViews();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    for (Clothes c : clothes) {
        String record = "ID=" + c.getID() + " | Category=" + c.getCategory() + " | " + c.getSize();
        Log.d("Record", record);
    }
}

Can anyone help?
```

Comment: Can we see the code for deleteCloth() ?

Comment: public Boolean deleteCloth(String id) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        return db.delete(SQLITE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null) > 0;

    }

Answer (score 0):

In your custom adapter call `this.notifyDataSetChanged();` where you are performing delete functionality and deleting that element from arrayList which is set to that adapter.

I mean remove the deleted value from the array list which you are passing to the Adapter and then call notifyDatasetChanged().

Hope this will help.

Comment: My delete method is in the databaseHandler so i don't understand what you are saying

Comment: I think your database handler method is returning you an arrayList of clothes, So pass that updated arraylist to adapter and perform notifyDataSetChanged on list.

Comment: Ottherwise please post the complete code, I will try to help in another way.

Comment: Ok thank you so much. I post the delete method in a comment above. I think I might need to change it.

Comment: Yes, return and new arrayList of remaining clothes  from this method and pass it to the adapter set adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting the object in item click listener.
So in that.

```
adapter.refreshlist(array after removing);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Now in Adapter class.

```
Public void refreshlist(Arraylist array){
   this.oldarray=array;
}
```

This will do work.